Trying to create a State provider using Riverpods code generation and can't create an instance of the provider
I'm new to riverpod. I'm trying to use the code generation API to create something that is like a state provider but I can't seem to create a usable instance of the provider.
This is my provider
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
part 'main_mode_provider.g.dart';

enum EditorMode {
  newFile,
  editFile,
}

@riverpod
class MainModeProvider extends _$MainModeProvider {
  @override
  EditorMode build() {
    return state;
  }
  void setEditorMode(EditorMode newMode) {
    state = newMode;
  }
}

final mainModeProvider = MainModeProvider();

The above is an a separate dart file.
In my main.dart I import this the provider dart file and try to watch a ref of it but am getting an error.
class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Widget page;
    EditorMode mode = ref.watch(mainModeProvider);

and I'm getting the following error on the last line
The argument type 'MainModeProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<EditorMode>'.

What am I doing wrong here? The code generation runs correctly.

return state;

You cannot "return state" in your build(), because the whole point of build() is to initialize state!
Also, because you named the class MainModeProvider, the name of your provider will be mainModeProviderProvider.  Might want to dial that back a bit.
